# Adding events to native calendar is not working

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-calendar

I am working on an Android application. I have to add events to native Android calendar. So I tried the following code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8 ) {
    l_eventUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
} else {
    l_eventUri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");
}

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver() .query(Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase(this)),new String[] { "calendar_id", "displayname"}, null,null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
// fetching calendars name
String CNames[] = new String[cursor.getCount()];
// fetching calendars id
int[] CalIds = new int[cursor.getCount()];
for (int i = 0; i < CNames.length; i++) {
    CalIds[i] = cursor.getInt(0);
    CNames[i] = cursor.getString(1);
    cursor.moveToNext();
}

// get calendar
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();     
Uri EVENTS_URI = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase(this) + "events");
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

// event insert
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("calendar_id",111);
values.put("title", "Reminder Title");
values.put("allDay", 0);
values.put("dtstart", cal.getTimeInMillis() + 11*60*1000); // event starts at 11 minutes from now
values.put("dtend", cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000); // ends 60 minutes from now
values.put("description", "Reminder description");
//Event Id
values.put("_id", 23);  
//0~ default; 1~ confidential; 2~ private; 3~ public
values.put("visibility", 0);
//0~ false; 1~ true
values.put("hasAlarm", 1);
//status: 0~ tentative; 1~ confirmed; 2~ canceled
values.put("eventStatus", 1);
//0~ opaque, no timing conflict is allowed; 1~ transparency, allow overlap of scheduling
values.put("transparency", 0);
Uri event = cr.insert(EVENTS_URI, values);

// reminder insert
Uri REMINDERS_URI = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase(this) + "reminders");
values = new ContentValues();
values.put( "event_id", Long.parseLong(event.getLastPathSegment()));
values.put( "method", 1 );
values.put( "minutes", 10 );
cr.insert( REMINDERS_URI, values );

private String getCalendarUriBase(Activity act) {
    String calendarUriBase = null;
    Uri calendars = Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars");
    Cursor managedCursor = null;
    try {
        managedCursor = act.managedQuery(calendars, null, null, null, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    if (managedCursor != null) {
        calendarUriBase = "content://calendar/";
    } else {
        calendars = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");
        try {
            managedCursor = act.managedQuery(calendars, null, null, null, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        if (managedCursor != null) {
            calendarUriBase = "content://com.android.calendar/";
        }
    }
    return calendarUriBase;
}
```

When I run this code, I am getting the `IllegalArgumentException`.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://com.android.calendar/
```

I think the error is because of `getCalendarUriBase()` method. I searched a lot for other ways, but so far most of the developers following the above code snippet because this will work for every Android versions. How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed `calendars` when you try to execute this line

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
    Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase(this)), /* <-- unknown URL content */
    new String[] { "calendar_id", "displayname" },
    null,null,null);
```

resulting in `IllegalArgumentException`.

Just add the `calendars` after `getCalendarUriBase(this)`.

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
    Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase(this)+"calendars"),
    new String[] { "_id", "displayName" },
    null,null,null);
```

> **Note:**
>
> - Use `_id` to get the calendar ID if you query from `calendars` table. `calendar_id` is defined as a foreign key in other tables (e.g. `events`).
> - Use `displayName` for GingerBread or below. For Ice Cream Sandwich and above, use `calendar_displayName`.

---

When adding an event, you need to include: calendar ID, start date, end date (or recurrence rule), and event timezone. You have included all but the timezone. Try adding

```
values.put("eventTimezone", TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
```

before inserting the event.

Comment: @Andrew..Thank you very much..now I am getting 1android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: calendar_id (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT calendar_id, displayname FROM Calendars..Please help me to fix this issue too...

Comment: Edited the code. Added some info you need to know regarding the calendar provider.

Comment: Hi Andrew..now the code is working but no events are created in calender...what I have to do?

Comment: First, check whether the `calendar_id` is correct or not. Second, you also need to define the time-zone for the event. Try adding `values.put("eventTimezone", TimeZone.getDefault().getID());`

Comment: I already added eventtimezone and where I have to change calender_id?..I changed here Cursor cursor = getContentResolver() .query(Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase(this)+"calendars" ),new String[] { "_id", "displayName" }, null,null, null);...In valued I am addind both calender_id and _id...there I had given some number ..

Comment: Check the `calendar_id` on this line: `values.put("calendar_id",111);`. For a test, try this instead `values.put("calendar_id",CalIds[0]);` to insert the event to the first calendar from the query.

Comment: now I got nullpointer exception for   values.put( "event_id", Long.parseLong(event.getLastPathSegment()));..

Comment: I see. That means 111 is valid for `calendar_id`. With current condition, I couldn't analyze why the event is not created. As the comments are already quite long, I suggest you to create new question regarding this issue (event not created) with the updated code.